# .htaccess 301 redirect page with no extension to a PHP page

Tags: linux, .htaccess, http-redirect

I'm having a problem getting an old WordPress site page to redirect to the new basic PHP site page.

Example: The old WordPress page with no extension is at `http://example.com/levelone/leveltwo/pagename`

The new page is at `http://example.com/directory/pagename.php`.

Here are several things I've tried:

```
redirect 301  /levelone/leveltwo/pagename http://example.com/directory/pagename.php
```

This did not work at all

Then I tried redirecting the directories first, then the page, like so:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/levelone/leveltwo/ http://example.com/directory/
redirect 301  /pagename http://example.com/pagename.php
```

This almost worked, but gave me the right URL but without the PHP extension.

I can't just redirect an old directory to a new one because there are actually many. The example is just one. The trouble seems to be going from a non-extension page to a page with the `.php` extension.

Here's another thing I tried:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/levelone/leveltwo/(.*)$ /directory/$1.php
redirect 301  /pagename http://example.com/pagename.php
```

This gave me `http://example.com/directory/pagename/.php`.

***Solved: I got it to work with the following:***

```
Redirect 301 /levelone/leveltwo/pagename/ http://example.com/directory/pagename.php
```

The problem seemed to be with the missing forward-slash after the old page name.

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer, and then accept your own answer. That will mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/levelone/leveltwo/(.*)$ /directory/$1.php
```

---

What's probably happening is the mod_alias and mod_rewrite aren't playing nice with each other. They're both in the URI-file mapping pipeline so when one does its processing, the URI (eventhough a redirect response is what's going to ultimately happen) continues to get processed, then when the redirect happens, the URI has been mangled by mod_rewrite.

You should just stick with mod_rewrite so that you can prevent any wordpress rules from doing its thing. Add these rules **above** any wordpress rules you have in your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?levelone/leveltwo/(.*)$ /directory/$1.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This got me closer, but maybe I'm still doing something wrong. I edited above the change but no cigar yet.

Comment: @user1687345 Oh you know what's probably happening... Let me explain in my edit

Comment: I'll give that a try. And... just to clarify, the site used to be WordPress, but is just a basic php site now, no WordPress present at all. What's happening is the old url's found in google are dead 404's so I need them to redirect to the newer php pages.

Comment: I used that and dropped the page redirect but still get the same result.

Comment: I got it to work by going back to the simple page redirect but adding the forward slash for the non-extension page name. See edit above

Comment: Appreciate the help, although it wasn't the solution, it was helpful in narrowing it down. I don't have enough points to give you a points up.